# Scroll Div with a Position Fixed child

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that wraps some content. This div has its overflow-y set to scroll.

Inside the wrapper, are 2 more divs. The first has a height greater than the wrapper, the second contains some content and is absolutely positioned.

```html
<div id="wrapper" style="overflow-y:scroll;height:500px">
  <div id="setHeight" style="height:1000px"></div>
  <div id="content" style="position:fixed">
    Content Goes Here
  </div>
</div>
```

The question is when the mouse is positioned over the `#content` `div`, the `#wrapper` will not scroll. However, when the mouse is positioned on some other part of the `#wrapper` `div` where the `#content` `div` doesn't fill it scrolls.

**I tried to fix this in various ways:**

**First:** set the `z-index` of `#content` to `-1`. This works (as in the `#wrapper` scrolls) but the content can no longer be interacted with.

**Second:**, apply the above fix, but use Javascript to listen for mouse clicks. When the user clicks, immediately change the `#content`'s `z-index` to `1` allowing the user to interact.

The problem with this is even though it works (i.e. the `z-index` changes), the browser still won't interact with the `#content` unless you let go of the mouse and click again. Which by the time you let go of the mouse I would want the `#wrapper` to be scroll-able again.

**Third:** I tried to set the `#content` `z-index` to `-1`, and set the `#wrapper`'s `pointer-events` to `none`. This however made both the scrolling and interaction stop.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#wrapper {
  background: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100px; border: solid 1px;}
#header {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 200px; overflow-y: none;}
#content {
  background: green;}
#popup {
  background: yellow;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">Headerum textum</div>
  <div id="content">
    Contentum Textum
    <div id="popup">
      Popup textum, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ... Aenean ut orci vel massa suscipit pulvinar. Nulla sollicitudin. Fusce varius, ligula non tempus aliquam, nunc turpis ullamcorper nibh, in tempus sapien eros vitae ligula.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please have a look... on this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/mzmZzx?editors=1100)

[image]

Comment: I would want the "Headerum textum" to scroll even when the mouse is on content with the yellow background.

Comment: that has no sense... the yellow has nothing to scroll, it's not a scrollable area, and the wrapper is even not under the mouse, the wrapper area is above the yellow field

Comment: as I look on the image updated above, I don't see what is to scroll in the yellow label, the black labeled wrapper is outside the mouse control

Comment: the absolute position of the yellow element is not scrollable, is a fixed element, and is not contained in the scrollable area of the parent element

Comment: Yes that's the problem, put the yellow text with a "top:0" and it will overlap the blue text. Even though the yellow text is within the wrapper div, it prevents the wrapper div from scrolling when you mouse over it

Comment: have a look on the updated code, it seems you missed an "s" in `pointer-events`

Comment: This does work, but as I explained in try #1 of my question, I wanted to be able to interact with the content. Pointer event's disables that ability. The wrapper scrolls because the mouse ignores the content

Comment: imagine the yellow box has a scrollbar... you asks that both the yellow and blue containers scrolling in the same time?

Comment: That's a good point, but ultimately yeah :D I figured this wasn't normal behavior but what you just said helps me understand why it breaks the standard. I ended up listening for wheel/touch events to simulate the scroll. I wanted to make a book that would flip pages when you scroll. However scrolling on mobile shows/hides the address bar which looked bad as the page resizes. So I wanted to listen to the scroll event of the wrapper instead of the body. Here's a small demo of what I'm working toward: http://amightywind.com/494/

Comment: humm... its interesting what you do... however I see the scrollbar even in desktop browser, I can use the scroll bar it to scoll pages, is funny )

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why do you need the setHeight div. Did some change to your code. Don't know if this is what you want.

```html
<div id="wrapper" style="overflow-y:scroll;height:500px;position:relative">
  <div id="setHeight" style="height:1000px"></div>
  <div id="content" style="position:absolute;top:0px;">
    Content Goes Here
  </div>
</div>
```